# Como posso mudar atributos de arquivos no windows com python?

Tags: python, windows, atributos

Estou tentando deixar um arquivo .txt oculto. Como posso fazer isso utilizando linha de comando python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No windows podes fazer assim:

```
import ctypes
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02

ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW('CAMINHO/PARA/FICHEIRO.txt',
                                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
if ret:
    print 'Ficheiro definido para oculto'
else:  # se retornar algum erro
    raise ctypes.WinError()
```

Resposta retirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549109/hide-folders-file-with-python).

Não testei porque não tenho windows, por isso não tenho a certeza se vai resultar, se não resultar diz que eu retiro a resposta daqui